# Converting ARBG to RGB with alpha blending

Tags: c#, colors

Let's say that we have an ARGB color:

```
Color argb = Color.FromARGB(127, 69, 12, 255); //Light Urple.
```

When this is painted on top of an existing color, the colors will blend. So when it is blended with white, the resulting color is `Color.FromARGB(255, 162, 133, 255);`

The solution should work like this:

```
Color blend = Color.White; 
Color argb = Color.FromARGB(127, 69, 12, 255); //Light Urple.      
Color rgb = ToRGB(argb, blend); //Same as Color.FromARGB(255, 162, 133, 255);
```

What is `ToRGB`'s implementation?

Comment: I just want to say that I find it awesome that "Light Urple" has survived 4 edits.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's called [alpha blending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing).

In psuedocode, assuming the background color (blend) always has 255 alpha. Also assumes alpha is 0-255.

```
alpha=argb.alpha()
r = (alpha/255)*argb.r() + (1 - alpha/255)*blend.r()
g = (alpha/255)*argb.g() + (1 - alpha/255)*blend.g()
b = (alpha/255)*argb.b() + (1 - alpha/255)*blend.b()
```

*note: you probably need to be a bit (more) careful about floating-point/int math and rounding issues, depending on language. Cast intermediates accordingly*

**Edited to add:**

If you don't have a background color with an alpha of 255, the algebra gets alot more complicated. I've done it before and it's a fun exercise left to the reader (if you really need to know, ask another question :).

In other words, what color C blends into some background the same as blending A, then blending B. This is sort of like calculating A+B (which isn't the same as B+A).

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but I want to add this:

```
Public Shared Function AlphaBlend(ByVal ForeGround As Color, ByVal BackGround As Color) As Color
    If ForeGround.A = 0 Then Return BackGround
    If BackGround.A = 0 Then Return ForeGround
    If ForeGround.A = 255 Then Return ForeGround
    Dim Alpha As Integer = CInt(ForeGround.A) + 1
    Dim B As Integer = Alpha * ForeGround.B + (255 - Alpha) * BackGround.B >> 8
    Dim G As Integer = Alpha * ForeGround.G + (255 - Alpha) * BackGround.G >> 8
    Dim R As Integer = Alpha * ForeGround.R + (255 - Alpha) * BackGround.R >> 8
    Dim A As Integer = ForeGround.A

    If BackGround.A = 255 Then A = 255
    If A > 255 Then A = 255
    If R > 255 Then R = 255
    If G > 255 Then G = 255
    If B > 255 Then B = 255

    Return Color.FromArgb(Math.Abs(A), Math.Abs(R), Math.Abs(G), Math.Abs(B))
End Function

public static Color AlphaBlend(Color ForeGround, Color BackGround)
{
    if (ForeGround.A == 0)
        return BackGround;
    if (BackGround.A == 0)
        return ForeGround;
    if (ForeGround.A == 255)
        return ForeGround;

    int Alpha = Convert.ToInt32(ForeGround.A) + 1;
    int B = Alpha * ForeGround.B + (255 - Alpha) * BackGround.B >> 8;
    int G = Alpha * ForeGround.G + (255 - Alpha) * BackGround.G >> 8;
    int R = Alpha * ForeGround.R + (255 - Alpha) * BackGround.R >> 8;
    int A = ForeGround.A;

    if (BackGround.A == 255)
        A = 255;
    if (A > 255)
        A = 255;
    if (R > 255)
        R = 255;
    if (G > 255)
        G = 255;
    if (B > 255)
        B = 255;

    return Color.FromArgb(Math.Abs(A), Math.Abs(R), Math.Abs(G), Math.Abs(B));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't need to know this pre-render, you could always use the win32 method of getpixel, I believe.

Note: typing on iPhone in the middle of Missouri with no inet access. Will look up real win32 example and see if there is a .net equivalent.

In case anyone cares, and doesn't want to use the (excellent) answer posted above, you can get the color value of a pixel in .Net via this link [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx)