# Convert RGB channels to integer ratios

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

When I get a color in the RGB format, how can I convert the channels to (approximate) integer ratios?
Example:

```
(255, 0, 0)   -> (1, 0, 0)
(255, 128, 0) -> (2, 1, 0)
(128, 64, 0)  -> (2, 1, 0)
(255, 1, 0)   -> (1, 0, 0)
(3, 2, 0) -> (3, 2, 0)
(11, 5, 0) -> (11, 5, 0) or possibly (2, 1, 0)
```

As you see, the result integers should be as small as possible, but still reasonably precise, so the error in hue would be indistinguishable to human eye.

I tried dividing all channels by their minimum and then round it, but it produces `(2, 1, 0)` for `(3, 2, 0)`, which is unnecessarily imprecise.

Comment: I think you will need a channel which by some algorithm will be declared as significant enough to become the unit ratio. For example (255, 128, 0) somehow 128 declared as the unit ratio 1, then the rest of the channels will divide by 128, then round it. We just need to figure the "channel for unit ratio" algorithm, and if there isn't any feasible channel as the unit ratio (such as your case with (3,2,1) then it just returns (3,2,1). Just my ideas, hope it helps :)

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?  What problem does this solve?  If you're trying to save memory, this won't save much.  If you're trying to characterize the hue, you should probably convert from RGB to the HSV color space.

Comment: @David Mixing light objects to produce a light of certain color in a game. There are only red, blue and green lights. I don't want to create 255 red lights, as this doesn't affect the hue.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I actually think you're looking for alpha-blending. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780/converting-arbg-to-rgb-with-alpha-blending

Answer (score 1):

You could try decreasing factors (1, 2, 4, 8, ... , 256) and calculate some "Rounding error". Then stick to the largest factor with acceptable error.

**-OR-**

Simply convert RGB to Hue, Saturation, Value (HSV) and pick the closest hue value on a limited set of hue values.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two reasonable strategies for calculating the best ratios. Both of them need an additional parameter for which you have to do some experiments to see what you think is still tolerable (1. maxRatio, 2. maxError):

1. *Find the best solution with no ratio bigger than the given maxRatio:*

   If you apply this strategy then one solution (if you don't care about performance too much) is to get the biggest color value and divide it by the max ratio (careful, no integer division, maybe need to cast to double) to get the factor `f`. Now you divide the other colors by `f` and round the result to get integers again. Multiply the retrieved ratios by `f` subtract the real color value, square it and take the sum of all. Store this error and repeat decreasing maxRatio by one. Until maxRatio is two or one. Find the smallest error and return the corresponding ratios. (This is just to simplify you can keep track only of the best solution so far and its error and don't need to store all of them.)
2. *Find the smallest ratios not exceeding maxError*

   This strategy is a little more difficult. If you care about performance even less then you can do as follows: Save a copy of original colors as best ratios found and one as current ratios. Then you start decreasing the values of current ratios until all but one value is 0 or the biggest value is 1 like this: Find the biggest value in current ratio, decrease it by 1 (if there are equal values choose the one with the bigger color value) then see if decreasing the other values of the current ratio reduces the error (if so, decrease). If the error of the current ratio is smaller than the maxError save it as best ratio. And continue decreasing.